# Create socket server using custom Network IPAddress

Tags: c#, .net

Can i create socket server using custom Network IPAddress like (10.1.0.1 or 10.1.0.2)

ie
1.

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("10.1.1.1"), 8001);
```

2.

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("10.1.1.2"), 8002);
```

Comment: So, what is wrong with your code?

Comment: There has to be a piece of hardware with the IP address.  You can't just create an IP in code.  The listener is always connects to local PC using the endpoint IPAddress.Any which is designed for a listener to connect.

Comment: When i set IPAddress as 127.0.0.1, it work as expected. But when i change IPAddress to other machine IP (IP exists in the same network). It says "The requested address is not valid in its context"